# How to save images to Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

For some odd reason, my images have stopped saving to parse. Before, my code worked fine and I have not made any changes to it at all.

Here is my code:

```
 var posts = PFObject(className: "Product")
            posts["shortDescription"] = productShortDescription
            posts["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            posts["longDescription"] = productLongDescription
            posts["title"] = productTitle
            posts["price"] = productPrice
            posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    //success saving, now save image

                    //create image data

                    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.newItemImageView.image)


                    //create parse file

                    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "upload_image.png", data: imageData)
                    posts["imagePNG"] = parseImageFile
                    posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {
                            // take user home
                            println("data uploaded")
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnHomeAfterUpload", sender: self)
                        }else {
                            println(error)

                        }


                    })

                }else {

                    println(error)
                }

            })
```

Everything else is stored perfectly, but what's the issue with my image data?
Thanks!

Comment: You are not saving parseImageFile you need to save that as well

Comment: it would have saved you approximately more than a few hours if you were to stop learning Swift and use ObjC instead and then use all the tutorials with Parse and have an app that does this and is up and working in about 4 hours. Parse has explicitly stated that they don't have much interest in supporting Swift and I agree, 7 years of ObjC history and now somehow Swift is easier, but it requies a knowledge of Apple stuff, so not to be mean, but the reality is this: if you use ObjC, then your life will be easier, it's not that hard to learn given how much info is out there.

Comment: watch this video from parse, they explain why they do not "support" in full throttle mode right now: http://blog.parse.com/categories/videos/ watch this video specifically "Ask Parse Anything – June Edition Is Here!"

Comment: I just started coding 2 months ago. I planned on learning majority of the langs out there. But I figured that since Swift is new for Apple, it will eventually become the primary lang to dev Apple products. Apple makes everything obsolete, to make way for what's new.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are not saving `parseImageFile`, so first `parseImageFile.SaveInBackground` and on success set it to `posts` and then save `posts` as well

Should be something like this

```
         var posts = PFObject(className: "Product")
                posts["shortDescription"] = productShortDescription
                posts["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                posts["longDescription"] = productLongDescription
                posts["title"] = productTitle
                posts["price"] = productPrice
                posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {
                        //success saving, now save image
                        //create image data
                        var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.newItemImageView.image)                            
                        //create parse file
                        var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "upload_image.png", data: imageData)
parseImageFile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
posts["imagePNG"] = parseImageFile
                        posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                            if error == nil {
                                // take user home
                                println("data uploaded")
                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnHomeAfterUpload", sender: self)
                            }else {
                                println(error)

                            }


                        })
})


                    }else {

                        println(error)
                    }

                })
```

I haven't test this code on editor you may find some syntax error, but it should be something like this...

so things is when you create parseImageFile and then saveInBackground and inside block set it posts and then save post again

Comment: I am understanding what you're saying. It makes sense. But I cannot wrap my head around the format. I should have added that I am new to mobile dev.

Comment: Where to save posts in background?

Comment: I have updated code, your code should be look like this, I haven't test on editor you might fix some some syntax issue...

Comment: PFObject save all related objects and PFFile is not an exception

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your code and it's works fine.

```
        let image = UIImage(named: "img.jpg")
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let file = PFFile(name: "img", data: data)

        let parseObj = PFObject(className: "testClass")
        parseObj["text"] = "hello"
        parseObj["image"] = file

        parseObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (_, _) -> Void in }
```

Try this, if this code will be works - easiest way for you is remove "Product" table and create it again.

Comment: I continuously tested my code, and for some reason, images that are taken with my camera are not saved to parse. Any ideas why?

Comment: My code works fine, like you said. Screenshots are posted with no problem.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of how field looks like. Is it (undefined)?

Comment: I can send photos yet, my rep is not high enough. But yes, the field says undefined and my tableview does not load because of the nil value.